# Plugins for Tags

Tags: plugins, tags, frontend-form

Is there any plugin for Tag that will be like:

- Text field in a front-end entry form where user can add multiple tags.
- After pressing the save button, the plugin should:
  check for every tag, whether it exists already (and create the tag if not).
- If tags exists it will act like autocomplete.
- save the tags together with the rest of the entry form (including the text field with the user defined tags)

Comment: Not that I know of, but I’m working on a project that will give you a lot of the core fields on the front end, but currently I don’t have Tags implemented. Follow along here if you are interested: https://github.com/joshangell/FFFields